# Mocking an interface which is { get; } only (Moq)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have an `IUnitOfWork` interface which contains mappings to all of our repositories, like so:

```
public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    IRepository<Client> ClientsRepo { get; }
    IRepository<ConfigValue> ConfigValuesRepo { get; }
    IRepository<TestRun> TestRunsRepo { get; }
    //Etc...
}
```

Our `IRepository` class looks like this:

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    T getByID(int id);
    void Add(T Item);
    void Delete(T Item);
    void Attach(T Item);
    void Update(T Item);
    int Count();
}
```

My issue is that I'm trying to test a method that makes use of `getById()`, however this method is accessed through an `IUnitOfWork` object, like this:

```
public static TestRun getTestRunByID(IUnitOfWork database, int testRun)
{
    TestRun testRun = database.TestRunsRepo.getByID(testRun);
    return testRun;
}
```

In my test I have mocked 2 things; `IUnitOfWork` and `IRepository`. I have configured the `IRepository` so that it returns a `TestRun` item, however I can't actually make use of this repo since in the `getTestRunByID()` method it gets its own repo from the `IUnitOfWork` object. As a result this causes a `NullReferenceException`.

I have tried adding my repo to the IUnitOfWork's repo but it will not compile since all repos are marked as { get; } only. My test is:

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetTestRunById_ValidId_TestRunReturned()
{
    var mockTestRunRepo = new Mock<IRepository<TestRun>>();
    var testDb = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>().Object;
    TestRun testRun = new TestRun();
    mockTestRunRepo.Setup(mock => mock.getByID(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(testRun);

    //testDb.TestRunsRepo = mockTestRunRepo; CAN'T BE ASSIGNED AS IT'S READ ONLY

    TestRun returnedRun = EntityHelper.getTestRunByID(testDb, 1);     
}
```

How can I get my `IUnitOfWork's` repo to not throw a `NullReferenceException`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't assign to a mock, you need to configure the properties via a Setup.

---

Instead of:

```
testDb.TestRunsRepo = mockTestRunRepo;
```

Try:

```
testDb.Setup(m => m.TestRunsRepo).Returns(mockTestRunRepo.Object);
```

or

```
testDb.SetupGet(m => m.TestRunsRepo).Returns(mockTestRunRepo.Object);
```

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you very much for your help (again!) :) I didn't think to return a repo from my IUnitOfWork, cheers

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll want something like this in your arrange:

```
testDb.Setup(n => n.TestRunsRepo).Returns(mockTestRunRepo.Object);
```

You're trying to assign something to the mocks object when it's far easier to just set the mock up and have it return what you want that way.

Comment: This won't work `n.TestRunsRepo()` suggests a method and this is a property. Needs to be `n.TestRunsRepo`