# Moq Unit Testing - expected result?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I'm using Moq for my Unit Tests and have got the following method:

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetTestRunById_ValidId_TestRunReturned()
{
    var mockTestRunRepo = new Mock<IRepository<TestRun>>();
    var testDb = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();

    testDb.SetupGet(m => m.TestRunsRepo).Returns(mockTestRunRepo.Object);

    TestRun returnedRun = EntityHelper.getTestRunByID(testDb.Object, 1);
}
```

The method in question which is being tested is getTestRunByID(). I have confirmed that this method is called when debugging this unit test, but as expected getTestRunByID() doesn't return anything since the mock has no data inside it.

Would all that matter is the method gets hit and returns null? If not, how can I add data to my mockTestRunRepo when it's only present as a returned value from testDb?

For reference the method being tested is:

```
public static TestRun getTestRunByID(IUnitOfWork database, int testRun)
{
    TestRun _testRun = database.TestRunsRepo.getByID(testRun);
    return _testRun;
}
```

Comment: You only want your Repo to return `null` if that is the behavior that you're expecting. If you're testing that data is returned, set it up to return something.

Comment: @krillgar I've updated my question, the other class structures involved can be found here if anyone wants a little bit more in-depth into how the other classes work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34789144/mocking-an-interface-which-is-get-only-moq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of the unit test is to ONLY test the small method `getTestRunByID`. For that, test if it was called exactly once with that integer parameters, `1`.

```
mockTestRunRepo.Verify(m => m.getByID(1), Times.Once());
```

You must also set up the method `getByID` for `mockTestRunRepo`, to make it return a specific value, and test if the result value of the test run is equal to what you expected.

```
//instantiate something to be a TestRun object.
//Not sure if abstract base class or you can just use new TestRun()
mockTestRunRepo.Setup(m => m.getByID(1)).Returns(something);
```

Test if you get the same value

```
TestRun returnedRun = EntityHelper.getTestRunByID(testDb.Object, 1);
Assert.AreEqual(returnedRun, something);
```

This code might be prone to errors, as I do  not have an environment to test it right now. But this is the general idea behind a unit test.

This way, you test if the method `getById` runs as expected, and returns the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

You have your repository return data the same way that you setup everything else.

```
var mockTestRunRepo = new Mock<IRepository<TestRun>>();

// This step can be moved into the individual tests if you initialize
// mockTestRunRepo as a Class-level variable before each test to save code.
mockTestRunRepo.Setup(m => m.getById(1)).Returns(new TestRun());
```

Per @Sign's recommendation, if you know that you're calling it with `1`, then use that instead of `It.IsAny<int>()` to keep things cleaner.

Comment: It should probably only return that test run if the correct number is passed in since you are supplying that as well.

Comment: Ideally this is what I would have liked to set-up and test, however if you look at how getTestRunByID() works it gets it's own repo from the passed IUnitOfWork object, so it would never make use of the mockTestRunRepo

Comment: Then you have issues with the way your code is structured. Find the way that your code gets the repo, and set it up that way.

Comment: I've tried adding my mockTestRunRepo (testDb.TestRunRepo = mockTestRunRepo) but it is set-up as { get; } only, so it can't be added